# My XSLT isnt working. I need to send data via xml and need to populate 'Y' for full time employees and 'N' for part time

Tags: xml, xslt, workday-api

I have a xslt code to send a data to third party system in form of XML. I need to populate 'Y' for full time employees and 'N' for part time employees.

This is my xslt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXE8d.png)

Here is my xml data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osfqe.png)

Comment: You need to post the code in your question.

Comment: Please post the code with question, it is very difficult to copy your code from image and provide you solution.

Answer (score 0):

The value in the variable `$Emp_type` by the below code will be `Full_time`.

```
<xsl:variable name="Emp_type" select="wd:Position_Time_Type/wd:ID[@wd:type='Position_Time_Type_ID']" />
```

Below condition

```
<xsl:when test="$Emp_type = 'Y'">
```

should be modified to

```
<xsl:when test="$Emp_type = 'Full_time'">
```

Below is the modified code.

```
<xsl:variable name="Emp_type" select="wd:Position_Time_Type/wd:ID[@wd:type='Position_Time_Type_ID']" />
<xsl:variable name="Emp_type_FT">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$Emp_type = 'Full_time'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'Y'" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'N'" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```